# How to create index in VARCHAR2 column?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, database-performance

I have two tables table1 and table2. We are joining both the tables using below condition

```
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table2.ID = tabe1.ID
AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(REPLACE(EXE_TS,'IST','')),
                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
    BETWEEN V_LAST_YEAR_DATE AND V_THIS_YEAR_DATE
```

The Data in ID and EXE_TS column are as below and both the columns are VARCHAR2
ID  example  'S001' and EXE_TS  '2018-12-13 09:23:13 IST'

I want to create an Index in the table2 column using ORD_ID and EXE_TS.  Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this lengthy operation is not needed.

You can replace

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(REPLACE(EXE_TS,'IST','')),
               'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
       'YYYY-MM-DD))
```

With

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE(REPLACE(EXE_TS,'IST'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

And you can create index on above expression as following:

```
Create index idx1
On your_table (
ord_id,
TRUNC(TO_DATE(REPLACE(EXE_TS,'IST'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: But while creating Index  i am getting ORA-0841(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999 and not in 0 error message

Comment: Because your column is a string and must contain the invalid string which is not the same as `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`. So it is recommended to give date as a data type to such columns.

Comment: I don't think it is a smart idea to hard-code the time zone as `IST`

Comment: Yes, it is also possible to remove everything after first space also